# .net web service

Tags: c#

i am calling a web service by aspx page  and wants my return output as a json format with a specific view like (grid view) in asp.net...so here is any view available in JSON which display my output like grid view..pls give me suggetion as soon as possible....thax
salman ansari

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, WebServices are based on XML SOAP objects, I anot sure if these can be handled like Json objects or converted. You could create a page (or view in MVC), that returns json objects specifically.